# Is there a way to join an integer to a string, that always contains an integer, in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

In Microsoft Access, I have two linked tables which I can't change the structure of.

One of these tables contains an ID in integer format, the other contains the same ID, but in string format.

I want to join on these fields, but, obviously, MS Access isn't letting me.

Is there a way, possibly using casting or something similar to create this join?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ID` is autonumber in `t1` and text in `t2`, you can use `CLng()` in the `ON` expression to transform `t2.ID` to long integer.

```
SELECT *
FROM
t1 INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.ID = CLng(t2.ID);
```

Or you could use `Val()` instead of `CLng()` for other `ID` numeric types.

I'm not sure how well the query designer will cooperate with this in Design View, but you can do it in SQL View.

OTOH, you may prefer to create a separate query, "qryT2", for `t2` which transforms the text ID to numeric.

```
SELECT CLng(ID) AS numeric_ID, t2.*
FROM t2;
```

Then you could substitute `qryT2` for `t2` in the first query, and have one which the query designer finds to be more congenial.

```
SELECT *
FROM
t1 INNER JOIN qryT2 
ON t1.ID = qryT2.numeric_ID;
```

Comment: Perfect, I have lost my design view but I'm doing something I really shouldn't be doing so I can't really complain. Thanks

Comment: I added a note about a workaround to restore design view.  It requires  creating an extra query, but query definitions don't consume significant space ... so maybe it's worth it for you.  Or you could do it as a derived table instead if you prefer not to create the extra saved query.

Comment: Thankyou, I will give this a shot whenever I get into work in the morning!

Answer (score 3):

Go to the `View > SQL View` in the designer, and change your join clause to:

```
ON CSTR(IntegerID) = StringID
```

Of course, your ID names may vary, but you should ge the idea.